# MasterPage with multiple contentplaceholders

Tags: asp.net, master-pages

I have a default.aspx file that is tied to the MasterPAge and ContentPlaceHolder1 and displays fine, is there a way to have another page say info.aspx auto display in ContentPlaceHolder2?

Comment: What you want is definitely possible, but can you describe the scenario a little more?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Think of ContentPlaceHolder's as "fill-in-the-blanks" for MasterPages.  I think what you're looking for is more along the lines of a User Control, which is a piece of content/functionality that you can plug in anywhere you want.

Answer (score 0):

If there a way you can turn the content of Info.aspx into a usercontrol( should be very easy ),

if so this is an easy problem to solve, put that new ascx in the placeholder on the masterpage.

On Master:

```
<div class="mainContent">
    <!-- Each Page Content Will Go Here -->
    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="cph_MainContent" runat="server">
    </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
</div>

<div class="bottomContent">
    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="cph_BottomContent" runat="server">
        <!-- Each Page will Display this UNLESS it referenced this placeholder -->
        <!-- Put you INFO.ASCX control here -->
    </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
</div>
```

then you just comment out or delete the tags for the 2nd place holder on you Content Pages:

```
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="cph_MainContent" runat="server">
 you page content
</asp:Content>

<%-- 
this will make the master use the content inside the holder on its own page

<asp:Content ID="Content3" ContentPlaceHolderID="cph_BottomContent" runat="server">

</asp:Content>
--%>
```